# How to write the text file after received the location?

Tags: android, sqlite, location

I'm implementing the application just like tracking the user's traveling.
Now I'm using the SQLite database which is record the location, time,and date 
then automatically send to the MySQL server via JSON if the Internet is connecting.

But I want to do like the following:

1) I would like to keep data as a text file of each traveling before send to server.

2) I don't know that I should record data in SQLite before write as a file or not?

3) I also need to list all files in the document menu to show user all files 
and check the status of all files are completely sent or did not send.

I tried to search for the good tutorial and any examples but did not find them yet.
If anyone have a good tutorial for write/read file and any idea for these, please suggests me.

Thank you so much

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Here](https://sites.google.com/site/androidhowto/how-to-1/save-file-to-sd-card) is good tutorial how to write data to file and save it to SD card.